# Add suffix to each line with shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to add some words at the end of each line of a text file. How can I do this with a Bash script?

Example: add the word `done` at the end of each line:

```
line1 abcdefg done
line2 abcdefg done
line3 abcdeft done
```

Answer (score 37):

Use awk:

```
awk 'NF{print $0 " done"}' inFile
```

OR sed with inline flag:

```
sed -i.bak '!/[^[:blank:]]/s/$/ done/' inFile
```

Comment: The problem with the solutions that they add an extra line with `done` at the end of file - this one is not wanted.

Answer (score 3):

Did I read [vim](/questions/tagged/vim)?

Content of `script.vim`:

```
set backup
g/^/ normal A done
normal ZZ
```

Run it like:

```
vim -S script.vim infile
```

It will modify the file in-place creating a backup with `~` suffix.

Answer (score 3):

sed is alway helpful for these kind of tasks,

```
 # cat append.txt
 line1 abcdefg
 line2 abcdefg
 line3 abcdeft

 # sed -i 's/$/done/g' append.txt

 # cat append.txt
 line1 abcdefg done
 line2 abcdefg done
 line3 abcdeft done
```

or

you can use the below script:

```
 # cat sedcheck.sh
 #!/bin/bash
 if [ $# -eq 0 ]
    then
      echo "No input supplied"
    else
      sed -i 's/$/ '$1'/g' $2
 fi


 # cat append.txt
 line1 abcdefg donedin
 line2 abcdefg donedin
 line3 abcdeft donedin

 # ./sedcheck.sh testing append.txt

 # cat append.txt
 line1 abcdefg donedin testing
 line2 abcdefg donedin testing
 line3 abcdeft donedin testing
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this in pure bash you could do:

```
#!/bin/bash

INFILE=$1
TMPFILE=/tmp/$INFILE.$$


while IFS= read -r; do
    echo "$REPLY done"; 
done <$INFILE >$TMPFILE ;

mv $TMPFILE $INFILE;
```

Which, if called `append.sh` can be called as such:

```
bash append.sh file.txt
```

**Edited** as per 1_CR's comments.

Comment: one would have thought the multiple appends to `$TMPFILE` within the loop could be replaced with a single `>$TMPFILE` at the end of the loop

Comment: @1_CR Indeed that would be better, I've changed the code to reflect this.

Comment: While you're at it, set `IFS` to null string and pass `-r` to `read`, something like `while IFS= read -r x;`.. read all about it [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/read). +1, BTW

Answer (score 0):

Perl way... same as that of the awk one liner

**Input**

```
line1 abcdefg 
line2 abcdefg 
line3 abcdeft
```

**Code**

```
  perl -lane 'print $F[0]," ",$F[1]," done"' Input
```

Comment: Better `"@F"` (note double quotes) that `$F[0]," ",$F[1]`. Just in case the line be longer (or shorter) than two words.