# Add a number to each line of a file in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have some files with some lines in Linux like:

```
2013/08/16,name1,,5000,8761,09:00,09:30
2013/08/16,name1,,5000,9763,10:00,10:30
2013/08/16,name1,,5000,8866,11:00,11:30
2013/08/16,name1,,5000,5768,12:00,12:30
2013/08/16,name1,,5000,11764,13:00,13:30
2013/08/16,name2,,5000,2765,14:00,14:30
2013/08/16,name2,,5000,4765,15:00,15:30
2013/08/16,name2,,5000,6765,16:00,16:30
2013/08/16,name2,,5000,12765,17:00,17:30
2013/08/16,name2,,5000,25665,18:00,18:30
2013/08/16,name2,,5000,45765,09:00,10:30
2013/08/17,name1,,5000,33765,10:00,11:30
2013/08/17,name1,,5000,1765,11:00,12:30
2013/08/17,name1,,5000,34765,12:00,13:30
2013/08/17,name1,,5000,12765,13:00,14:30
2013/08/17,name2,,5000,1765,14:00,15:30
2013/08/17,name2,,5000,3765,15:00,16:30
2013/08/17,name2,,5000,7765,16:00,17:30
```

My column separator is "`,`" and in the third column (currently `,,`), I need the entry number within the same day.  For example, with date
2013/08/16 I have 11 lines and with date 2013/08/17 7 lines, so I need add the numbers for example:

```
2013/08/16,name1,1,5000,8761,09:00,09:30
2013/08/16,name1,2,5000,9763,10:00,10:30
2013/08/16,name1,3,5000,8866,11:00,11:30
2013/08/16,name1,4,5000,5768,12:00,12:30
2013/08/16,name1,5,5000,11764,13:00,13:30
2013/08/16,name2,6,5000,2765,14:00,14:30
2013/08/16,name2,7,5000,4765,15:00,15:30
2013/08/16,name2,8,5000,6765,16:00,16:30
2013/08/16,name2,9,5000,12765,17:00,17:30
2013/08/16,name2,10,5000,25665,18:00,18:30
2013/08/16,name2,11,5000,45765,09:00,10:30
2013/08/17,name1,1,5000,33765,10:00,11:30
2013/08/17,name1,2,5000,1765,11:00,12:30
2013/08/17,name1,3,5000,34765,12:00,13:30
2013/08/17,name1,4,5000,12765,13:00,14:30
2013/08/17,name2,5,5000,1765,14:00,15:30
2013/08/17,name2,6,5000,3765,15:00,16:30
2013/08/17,name2,7,5000,7765,16:00,17:30
```

I need do it in bash. How can I do it?

Comment: Take a look at `awk` or `sed`. See their man pages and look for examples onthe internet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [shell script add suffix each line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16991035/shell-script-add-suffix-each-line)

Comment: Not the same as the proposed duplicate.  Cries out for `awk`.

Answer (score 4):

This one's good too:

```
awk -F, 'sub(/,,/, ","++a[$1]",")1' file
```

Output:

```
2013/08/16,name1,1,5000,8761,09:00,09:30
2013/08/16,name1,2,5000,9763,10:00,10:30
2013/08/16,name1,3,5000,8866,11:00,11:30
2013/08/16,name1,4,5000,5768,12:00,12:30
2013/08/16,name1,5,5000,11764,13:00,13:30
2013/08/16,name2,6,5000,2765,14:00,14:30
2013/08/16,name2,7,5000,4765,15:00,15:30
2013/08/16,name2,8,5000,6765,16:00,16:30
2013/08/16,name2,9,5000,12765,17:00,17:30
2013/08/16,name2,10,5000,25665,18:00,18:30
2013/08/16,name2,11,5000,45765,09:00,10:30
2013/08/17,name1,1,5000,33765,10:00,11:30
2013/08/17,name1,2,5000,1765,11:00,12:30
2013/08/17,name1,3,5000,34765,12:00,13:30
2013/08/17,name1,4,5000,12765,13:00,14:30
2013/08/17,name2,5,5000,1765,14:00,15:30
2013/08/17,name2,6,5000,3765,15:00,16:30
2013/08/17,name2,7,5000,7765,16:00,17:30
```

Comment: Similarly: `awk -F, -v OFS=, '{$3=++a[$1]}1' file`

Comment: +1 !! this answer is better than mine..++a[$1] is so nice!. btw the last `1` could be omitted.

Comment: I am a bit confused where the constant 11/12 is? (noob to awk)