# Linux: Append Word Count to Each Line of a File

Tags: linux, bash, shell, csv, append

Quite new to Linux at the moment,

I've seen some straightforward answers for appending a constant/non-changing word/component to the end of a file e.g. [shell script add suffix each line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16991035/shell-script-add-suffix-each-line)

However, I'd like to know how to append the word count for each line of a .csv file to the end of each line, so that:

```
word1, word2, word3
foo1, foo2
bar1, bar2, bar3, bar4
```

Becomes:

```
word1, word2, word3, 3
foo1, foo2, 2
bar1, bar2, bar3, bar4, 4
```

I am working with comma separated values, so if there is a quicker/simpler way to do it by making use of the commas rather than the items, then that would work as well.

Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

Simple `awk` solution:

```
awk -F ',' '{print $0", "NF}' file.csv
```

- `-F` argument can be used to specify the field separator, `,` in your case.
- `$0` will contain the entire line
- `NF` is the variable that contains the number of fields in the line

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
while read line; do

N=`echo $line | wc -w`;
echo $line", "$N;

done < inputfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

a simple (yet most likely slow) bash script could do the trick:

```
#!/bin/bash

newfile=$1.tmp

cat $1 | while read l ; do

  echo -n $l \ >> $newfile
  echo $l | wc -w  >> $newfile

done
```

then move files according to your liking (be save by using `tempfile` ...)
for file:

```
one,
one, two,
one, two, three,
```

I get:

```
one,  1
one, two,  2
one, two, three,  3
```